# Magento discount products according to when they were created

Tags: magento

Is it possible to discount product according to when they were created/added onto the system.

I'm using Magento 1.6 and would like to apply a discount to all products added last year.

Answer (score 0):

Product creation date is not available for shopping cart price rules by default.
No such attribute is available in the manage attributes section at the backend

Suggestion:
1)Create a new attribute "product_creation_date" of type "date" for all products. 
2)Set "Use for Promo Rule Conditions" to yes for "product_creation_date".
3)For each product get the creation date using

```
$_product->getCreatedAt();
```

4)Set this value as the "product_creation_date".
5)Once you are done, play with promo codes using "product_creation_date" attribute.

Comment: This is one solution, but it has its disadvantages.  You would have to maintain dates for new products added, unless you coded a way to autofill this attribute.  I wwas hoping there might be an extension or a way to hack the databases which would make created date visible in the backend so you could manage it.

Comment: Ok deciding to go with this method.  However I'm making sure future dates are enetered automatically.  To do this I've added a bit of javascript to the edit product page which auto fills the date field.  The trouble is the date field shows a decimal like '0.3777777' instead of '19/03/2012'.  I think that the date box has its own conversion going on, changing my perfectly formatted date to something else.

Comment: well practically if you just need to give discounts on the products added last year, you may as well just store the "year_created". This would be an integer and this way there will be no auto conversion of dates to float.